# Is there a way to install the package openjdk8 and to prevent perl to update on FreeBSD 9.2 ?

Tags: freebsd

I am currently trying to find a way to install the package openjdk8 on a FreeBSD 9.2. 
To do that I used :

> sudo pkg install openjdk8

It worked without any problem. However, this has also updated the perl package to the version 5.24. We have many scripts that work only with perl 5.16.3 so I would like to keep this version of perl.

I already tried to uninstall the perl 5.24 package and to reinstall perl 5.16.3 and it worked. So I am convinced openjdk doesn't really need to update this package. I already tried to lock the package perl 5.16.3 but openjdk8 refuse to install himself. I have this message :

> perl 5.16.3 is locked and may not be modified

The installation ends and my package is not installed. Also, for specific reasons I don't want to use the port method. I absolutely want to use the pkg method.

So my question is this one : Is there a way to complete my installation of openjdk8 and to prohibit perl to update ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found an answer to my question. By installing my package offline, it installs the minimum of dependencies. It's not a very popular way to install packages on FreeBSD but it works very well.

Just follow this :

> sudo pkg install -F openjdk8

This command allow you to just fetch your packages and its dependencies. Once it's done, you have to find the location of the packages you just fetched.

> sudo find / -n *.txz -print

For me the result was

> /var/cache/pkg/openjdk8-8.112.16_1-1baeb24a94.txz

Then I go to this directory with :

> cd /var/cache/pkg

Now you just have to use :

> sudo pkg-static add openjdk8

That's all. It will extract the package and the minimum of dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are updating other packages and therefore is updating Perl, when installing `openjdk8` no other dependencies are fetched also there is no perl dependency in the [port Makefile](https://svnweb.freebsd.org/ports/head/java/openjdk8/Makefile?view=markup).

This is the output when installing only `openjdk8`:

```
# pkg install openjdk8
Updating FreeBSD repository catalogue...
FreeBSD repository is up to date.
All repositories are up to date.
Checking integrity... done (0 conflicting)
The following 1 package(s) will be affected (of 0 checked):

New packages to be INSTALLED:
        openjdk8: 8.152.16

Number of packages to be installed: 1

The process will require 165 MiB more space.
```

Indeed you can install the package without having Perl.

What you can do is install `openjdk8` and then install the version of Perl that you require, at the end, it should not modify/affect the `openjdk8` package.

Also, this could be useful,

```
pkg install --dry openjdk8
```

This will check what will be installed.

And in case there is a dependency (let's say you don't have perl) this you could try this:

```
pkg install --ignore-missing openjdk8
```